# Renumbering our task IDs in Microsoft Project to a different scale?

Tags: ms-project, tasks

We want to make our Task ID's in microsoft project 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4 and so on so it is clear which general task they fall under.
At the moment they are displayed as 1,2,3,4,5.

Please help, thank you

Comment: I think you just need to indent (change outline level) on the tasks you want to be subordinate. Perhaps I don't fully understand your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to display the Work Breakdown Structure (WBS) as a column on the sheet.

By default, this will number the tasks as per your request:
[image]

If this meets your requirement it is very easy to do. Right-click in the top bar of the sheet, at the position where you want the column, and select "Insert Column". Choose the column "WBS" and you have the result you want. Note that the original row / task numbers will still be present in the left margin, but one way round that is to drag that column's margin so that it has zero width.